# Which wysiwyg editor works fine with fancybox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tinymce, fancybox

I used to work with tinymce, but it causes lot of troubles when I want to put it to fancybox (fails with second start of fancybox window). Cleditor doesn't work too (displays "true" instead of editor). Is there any editor which will work without making any strange tricks?

**Edit:**

```
$('.fancybox_with_wysiwyg').fancybox({padding: 1, scrolling: 'no',
        beforeShow: function () { tinymce.execCommand('mceToggleEditor', false, 'fbwysiwyg'); },
        beforeClose: function () { tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', true, 'fbwysiwyg'); }
    });
```

**Edit2** (fixed callbacks)

```
  $('.fancybox_with_wysiwyg').fancybox({
    padding: 1,
    scrolling: 'no',
        onComplete : function() {
            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceToggleEditor', false, 'fbwysiwyg');
   },
        onCleanup : function() {
            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'fbwysiwyg' );
    }        
});
```

**Solution** (thanks to Thariama)

```
    $('.fancybox_with_wysiwyg').fancybox({padding: 1, scrolling: 'no',
            onComplete: function () { tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'fbwysiwyg'); },
            onClosed: function () { tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'fbwysiwyg' );  }
        });
```

Comment: Any editor should work if configured properly. If you post the specific errors, we will try to help. Otherwise your question will likely get closed.

Comment: Thanks for help. So, let's try with tinymce one more time. There is no specific error. When I start fancybox with my tinymce, everything works ok. But with any other start, editor is disabled. I think that something is wrong with closing it. Look at updated post.

Comment: Please include the code that you tried.

Comment: @zachar: yes, something is wrong with closing it (see my answer). You need to shut down an editor instance before creating another one with the same editor id, otherwise the initialization will fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>I used to work with tinymce, but it causes lot of troubles when I want to put 
>it to fancybox (fails with second start of fancybox window).
```

The simple solution for this case is to shut down tinymce correctly before you reinitialize it the second time.

To shut your editor instance down call

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'fbwysiwyg' );
```

**Update:** You need to use

```
$('.fancybox_with_wysiwyg').fancybox({padding: 1, scrolling: 'no',
        beforeShow: function () { tinymce.execCommand('mceToggleEditor', false, 'fbwysiwyg'); },
        beforeClose: function () { tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'fbwysiwyg' );  }
    });
```

Comment: Well, I'm confused. At now I can't even close my fancybox window. I will be grateful, if you take a look at my function (I will update first post)

Comment: There are no beforeShow and beforeClose callbacks in fancybox. Can I use onStart and onClosed instead of them (checked, both works)? I just trying to implement your solution, but something is wrong still, and tinyMCE fails with second start of fancybox.

Comment: Your advices leaded me to solution. Thanks!

Comment: I've already pasted the solution in first post :) Probably callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) definately works as I've been working on putting it inside a Fancybox this afternoon :)

The problem you may encounter is when a modal window plugin removes and recreates the textarea within the modal. In this case you will need to re-bind the WYSIWYG when the textarea is shown.

Comment: HOW do you re-bind it? Can you give an example?

Comment: CKEditor works ok in Fancybox, except when it comes to Chrome, I've been having real problems with that!